# After importing the sample data in magento the login is not working

Tags: magento, authentication

I have installed the Magento on wamp (Localhost). Then i have importeded the sample data from the magento web. after this,

1. I can't able to login on it
2. i click forget password but does not get any email
3. I see the admin_User table which is empty

Before installing the sample data it is working fine.
Any Solution.

Comment: Make sure app/etc/local.xml has the correct DB settings and delete the var/cache content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly follow the following Steps to run it successfully.

1) Import the sample data in Blank DB
2) Run the Installation Step of Magento and at the Time of Database name, give the database name in which you have imported sample data.
3) finish the installation.

All done. Now you can see frontend and login into admin panel as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you have backup then then import this 4 table in your database

1)admin_user
2)admin_rule
3)admin_role
4)admin_assert

then refresh and check it.

Comment: From magento web (You must install sample data on the file system and in the database before you install Magento)
I have reinstall db and media then configure them the problem is still there.